# Движение прямоугольника

Tags: c++builder

Как сделать, чтобы в таймере прямоугольник (rectangle) прорисовывался по х от 10 до 100, например?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берете PaintBox (как самый оптимальный для рисования).
Форме добавляете приватную переменную, int xpos;
Также берете таймер. настраиваете интервал.
Теперь нужно написать два обработчика. Вначале для таймера

```
xpos = xpos + 10;
if (xpos > 100) xpos = 0;
PaintBox1->Invalidate;
```

Первые две строки меняют координату. Третья сообщает PaintBox1, что нужно обновиться.

теперь для PaintBox1.onPaint. Она будет вызываться, когда системе нужно обновить его вид (либо когда мы попросили это с помощью Invalidate).

```
PaintBox1->Canvas->Rectangle(xpos, 10, xpos+20, 30);
```

Все, запускаем, наслаждаемся

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Еще вопрос: у меня график в цикле из n rectangle разной длины, как сделать, чтобы они прорисовывались до конца и не исчезали?